# MYSQL - Warning: Integer display width is deprecated

Tags: mysql

I'm seeing this warning:
MYSQL - Warning: #1681 Integer display width is deprecated.
MySQL version: 8.0.21

In the past, I had columns with display width (INT(20)) but I removed all of them.
As you can see there are no columns with display width:

query:

```
select count(*), COLUMN_TYPE from information_schema.`COLUMNS`
WHERE COLUMN_TYPE LIKE "%int%"
GROUP by COLUMN_TYPE;
```

results:

```
count(*) column_type
    2068 bigint
      96 tinyint(1)
    2285 int
    1267 bigint unsigned
      32 tinyint
      74 int unsigned
       6 smallint unsigned
       1 tinyint unsigned
       1 smallint
```

As I read, tinyint(1) is ignored:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-19.html

The question is, how I can make this warning go away :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: But what is the problem/question?

Comment: All int use  the same amount of bytes independent of the number behind the INT , so it was correct to delete it.

Comment: @akina, The question is, how I can make this warning go away :)

Comment: Relevant discussion for better understanding what is this number (display width) and why it was removed for integer types: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=98250